# How to ignore parts inside parenthesis when splitting by a word in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string as below.

```
var str = "SELECT COL1 , COL2 , (SELECT COL1 FROM TBL2 AS COL4) ,COL5 FROM TBL1 WHERE 1 = 1 ";
```

I want to split this by the word 'FROM' and also want to ignore the occurrence inside the parenthesis.

Expected output :

```
var arr = ['SELECT COL1 , COL2 , (SELECT COL1 FROM TBL2 AS COL4) ,COL5 ' , 'TBL1 WHERE 1 = 1'];
```

This string is just an example. String is dynamic and what I want to do is split by a word (ex:FROM) but ignore the occurences inside parenthecis.

Similar questions were there, but not explained for splitting by a word.

Comment: Regex is not the right tool for this job; you need a SQL parser.

Comment: This is just a question about  string manipulation , not a SQL related one though I used a SQL query ppart as the string

Comment: You are missing the crux of my comment.  Regex isn't designed/able to do complex parsing, which is what you need here.  The context of the keyword `FROM` determines how a split should happen.  Regex doesn't "know" anything about context.

Comment: yes. That's why I removed the tag regx.

Answer (score 0):

First we have to get 2nd occurrence of FROM in the string and then we need to split it from the 2nd occurrence.

Just try this code:

```
var str = "SELECT COL1 , COL2 , (SELECT COL1 FROM TBL2 AS COL4) ,COL5 FROM TBL1 WHERE 1 = 1 ";
var index=str.split("FROM", 2).join("FROM").length; //getting 2nd occurrence of FROM
var str1=str.slice(0, index);
var str2=str.slice(index);
var arr = [str1,str2];
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This string is just an example. String is dynamic and what I want to do is split by a word (ex:FROM) but ignore the occurences inside parenthecis.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned it in the question. Have wasted my time. Anyways from next time please clearly mention your question.

Comment: ' How to ignore parts inside parenthesis when splitting by a word in javascript '  This is the title i used. I thought it was helpfull to understand my requirement. Anyway sorry for the inconvinence caused.